# Как организовать регулярное выражение в $config['permitted_uri_chars']?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, codeigniter

Добрый день! У меня есть вопрос насчет `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` в `CodeIgniter`.
По умолчанию значение `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-;`
Как тут организовать регулярку, чтобы можно было разрешить написать любой символ в url?

Answer (score 1):

Любые символы:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '.';
```

Если под "любыми символами" подразумеваюся русские буквы: [тынц мышой](http://www.code-igniter.ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%B2_URL).

[Ответы на другие вопросы](http://www.code-igniter.ru/wiki/).

Comment: не работает

Answer (score 0):

[Решение проблемы с русскими символами в URL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/40465/) - статья на хабре.